# Expressing Impossibility in the Future

Tags: ambiguity, modal-verbs

What are the possible meanings of the following sentence:

```
He can't be coming tomorrow.
```

I think it has the following two possible meanings:

```
It is impossible that he will be coming tomorrow.
He is not allowed to come tomorrow.
```

Comment: The second 'allow' interpretation doesn't sound right at all.

Comment: What do you say about the first? I read the following sentence in a story: You can't be coming to rescue him every time he gets into trouble.

Comment: Ah.. context is very important (and you should give as much context in your question as you can; please edit for others). The literal meaning of 'cannot' is impossibility. So a sentence standing alone with 'cannot' will mean impossibility. In your longer sentence, 'cannot' does have a shade of meaning towards 'shouldn't'; It would be bad for you if you came every time. There's no sense of someone allowing or not. But I wouldn't be surprised if there were a situation in which 'cannot' does imply 'not allowed'. Modals (eg can will should must) have many meanings and even more implications.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the only time someone would use that wording is to express their dismay at the inconvenient imminent arrival of someone they weren't ready to receive:

> A: I just wanted to remind you that Sam is coming to stay with us on the 10th.
>   B: But that's... that's tomorrow! He *can't* be coming *tomorrow*! I'm not ready for him yet!

Comment: I read the following sentence in a story: You can't be coming to rescue him every time he gets into trouble. (How do you interpret it?)

Comment: @KaptanSingh: Well, that's not future, now, is it?

Comment: @Erik Kowal. It could also be expressing (deduced) impossibility if, for example, B's response in your dialogue were "He can't be coming tomorrow. He's still in the middle of Patagonia".

Comment: @tunny - Fair point. I did not think of that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of this sentence, once taking into account the full context, is very subtle and is often used by a person external to both you *and* the third-party subject. In essence is means that the activity under discussion, whilst acceptable in some small amount, would be preposterous if continued to the extent advised.

That is to say, in this example, "It is somewhat acceptable, or at least understandable, that you came to rescue him when he got into trouble *this time*, but if you took this action every time he got into trouble that would be preposterous". It also implies that 'he' gets into trouble often.

It is a very roundabout way of saying "Don't come and rescue him every time he gets into trouble".

I have experienced this when I sent an email to the CEO of the company I worked for and the response I received from his PA was "He can't be expected to answer emails on this subject", which was British English code for "You are not important enough to send emails to the CEO, please stop immediately", but neatly avoids telling me I am not important enough.

I also saw this behaviour from a singer on stage being lauded by the audience who were shouting "Elvis" at him, in honour of his great rock 'n' roll performance. His reply was "Don't be calling me no Elvis". In other words "It is preposterous that you are comparing me with Elvis".

No doubt there are shades of meaning even more subtle in this kind of usage, which essentially says "avoid getting into the state where you exhibit *this* behaviour", but this is a broad-brush flavour.